# Node sendmail opendkim mail.private permission denied

Tags: node.js, sendmail, dkim

Hello i want to sign emails with private key before sending, on my ubuntu server.
I have node and sendmail package installed.
Here is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sendmail = require('sendmail')({
    silent: true,
    dkim: {
      privateKey: fs.readFileSync('/etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/mail.private', 'utf8'),
      keySelector: 'mail'
    }
  })
```

On my server, the file /etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/mail.private has chmod 600 and chown opendkim:opendkim.
When i run:

```
sendmail({
        from: 'test@example.com',
        to: 'address@ethereal.email',
        subject: 'subject',
        html: html,
      }, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack);
    });
```

It doesn't work. In logs this error appears:
*Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/etc/opendkim/keys/example.com/mail.private'*
What is the problem here?
I understand that the problem is in permissions. The question is how to do it properly, without changing chmod more then 600.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in path. The path to the key must be exactly like this /etc/opendkim/keys/mail.private

And my working /etc/opendkim.conf file:

```
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
Syslog                  yes
UMask                   002
SyslogSuccess           Yes
LogWhy                  Yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
UserID opendkim:opendkim
Mode                    sv
OversignHeaders         From
Domain                  [edited domain]
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/keys/mail.private
Selector                mail
SOCKET                  inet:8891@127.0.0.1
```